Shiu's theorem for $4$ and $6$
I recently learned about Shiu's theorem, which states that for any $a,n$ with $(a,n)=1$, there are arbitrarily long strings of consecutive primes congruent to $a$ modulo $n$.
My question is about a remark Shiu makes early in the paper about the cases where $n$ is $4$ or $6$ (and $a = \pm 1$). In these cases, Shiu claims that it is possible to prove the result by considering the sum $$
\sum_p \chi(p)
$$ where $\chi$ is the unique non-principal character. I would like either a reference to such an argument, or a sketch of how such an argument might go.
